# FileNotFoundError during Google API Oauth2 Authentication

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate into Google's machine learning API using this github example: https://gist.github.com/ymotongpoo/1907281

My Python script is kicking off the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\step-by-step-build.py", line 39, in
> >
> > > Popen(["open", url])
> >
> > File "C:\Users\aearle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
> >
> > > restore_signals, start_new_session)
> >
> > File "C:\Users\aearle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
> >
> > > startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I am new to Oauth2 and am trying to authenticate into the ml API in order to deploy a machine learning model I trained. But I'm having trouble getting the authentication to work. Does anybody have experience with this who can help me out?

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
import base64
import json
import sys
import os
import time
import re
import googleapiclient
import requests

from subprocess import Popen

global authorization_code

client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
redirect_uri = "https://www.sample.com/r0-23940"
base_url = r"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/"
authorization_code = ""
access_token = ""

authorization_code_req = {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "scope": (r"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" +
              r" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" +
              r" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
    }

r = requests.get(base_url + "auth?%s" % urlencode(authorization_code_req),
                 allow_redirects=False)
url = r.headers.get('location')
Popen(["open", url])

authorization_code = raw_input("\nAuthorization Code >>> ")

access_token_req = {
    "code" : authorization_code,
    "client_id" : client_id,
    "client_secret" : client_secret,
    "redirect_uri" : redirect_uri,
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    }
content_length=len(urlencode(access_token_req))
access_token_req['content-length'] = str(content_length)

r = requests.post(base_url + "token", data=access_token_req)
tokens = json.loads(r.text)

access_token = tokens['access_token']
authorization_header = {"Authorization": "OAuth %s" % access_token}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script was posted 6 years ago and is probably outdated so I wouldn't rely on it in your place.

You could use ML API library for python: [api-client-library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)

Start with setting the proper credentials by using a service account key in JSON format. Steps: [1](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account), [2](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable).

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Once this is done use the library as described [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#building-and-calling-a-service). The api-client-library generates the methods dynamically after interaction with the [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/ml/v1/python/latest/) so they can be used as reference, as well as, [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects) and this.

For example if you want to list your jobs first consult the relevant [API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/ml/v1/ml.projects.jobs.list).

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
ml = build('ml', 'v1')
ml.projects().jobs().list(parent='projects/[PROJECT_NAME]').execute()
```

You can see that the python command follows the structure of the endpoint.

### Also:

Here other APIs supported by this library.
The library [reference](http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/index.html).

Comment: Long ongoing question become convoluted and messy and tags stop reflecting their content.  This raises the entry barrier it.  This also makes it more difficult for others to find a solution in it. I would say that as soon as you have a different question you should separate it. Think of it in terms of what will call more attention of the people who are able to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @AndyEarle also avoid posting your project name as this information is considered sensetive by Google.